# Unable to render XML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, syntax

When trying to store XML in variables and then render it, nothing is displayed.

Example XML string data: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

In the script below, `testvar1` is rendered, but not `testvar2`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="target"></div>
<script>
    var testvar1 = "balls";
    var testvar2 = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`;
    document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = testvar1 + testvar2;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't think of a reason for this not to work. But I'm probably overlooking something that is obvious to everyone else...

Comment: I don't think it is related to it being defined as a template-literal.  I just tested, and even if I wrap it in single-quotes it doesn't render...

Comment: @AlexanderNied If I put a simple string inside the back-ticks it works. Something like `yes` works. But `<yes></yes>` does not work. It seems all XML tags are being discarded.

Comment: Right, I'm just saying that if you write it as `var testvar2 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';` you get the same result; the template-literal seems unrelated to the issue.

Comment: @AlexanderNied I see your point now. I have updated the question title so that it is no longer specific to template literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious reason is that browser interprets your XML as valid tags and tries to render elements of your XML. If you want to display pure XML to the user, use `textContent` property instead of `innerHTML`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="target"></div>
<script>
    var testvar1 = "balls";
    var testvar2 = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`;
    document.getElementById("target").textContent = testvar1 + testvar2;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a very important distinction. Really good to know this now. Thank you. This also explains why `innerHTML` worked on an inline SVG, but not other XML.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a code that can be rendered because xml tag with attributes cannot be rendered by the browser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

If you want render it, you must skip HTML tags like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="target"></div>
    <script>
      var testvar1 = "balls";
      var testvar2 = `&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;`;
      document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = testvar1 + testvar2;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```